# Multi-line search with sed

Tags: sed

I need to append a few lines to a configuration file. The format is something like follows:

```
[Topic1]
param=foo
param=bar
param=foobar

[Topic2]
param=one
param=two
```

etc...

I am trying to write a script using sed to append parameters to a specific topic. Since all the topics have `param=`, I can't just insert a line after the last occurrence of that string. Also, I can't count on the value of the last parameter being consistent so for example I can't just insert a line after the string `param=two`

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not too familiar with mutliline sed-fu.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have any code you have tried, please add that to your question.

Comment: asked and answered a hundred times, just search the archives.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i -r ':a; N; $!ba; s/\[Topic1\]\n(param=[a-zA-Z]*\n)*/&param=VALUE\n/g' FILE_NAME`

Basically what `:a; N; $!ba;` doing is append all line when not the last line (`N`) to the tag created by `:a` so that we can use `\n` in our expression.

Then match [Topic1] followed by arbitrary number of param=xxx, and append param=VALUE to the end of the matching result (`&`).